# Understanding the proof that the differential is zero at a local maximum (multivariable real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am self studying analysis of several variables using the text "Mathematical analysis" by Andrew Browder and I am trying to understand this proof:

[image]

1. In the highlighted part, I was wondering why is the sign of $r(tv)$ unchanged when we moved it to the right side of the inequality? Was there a typo?
2. Is it true that $\frac{r(h)}{|h|} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ imply that $\frac{r(tv)}{t} \to 0$ as $t \to 0$? But don't we need
3. So assuming, there is no mistakes in the text, I am trying to prove the other direction: $Lv\geq 0$. Is this correct: Replacing $v$ with $-v$, we have $L(-tv)+r(-tv)\leq 0$ so $-tLv \leq -r(-tv)$ which implies $Lv \geq \frac{r(-tv)}{t}$ and taking $t \to 0$, we have $Lv \geq 0$.

I know these are probably very simple questions, but I have having some trouble understanding the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the sign should be switched: $L(v)\leq \frac{-r(tv)}{t}$.
2. Yes, this is true, and it's a very good exercise in unwinding definitions.
3. Sure, what you did is fine. But note that you're doing excessive work by repeating the argument again (hence more error-prone). By steps 1 and 2, you already know that for **every** $v\in\Bbb{R}^n$, we have $L(v)\leq 0$. This is enough to prove $L=0$ because for every $v\in\Bbb{R}^n$ we have $L(v)\leq 0$, and also $L(-v)\leq 0$ (because $-v$ obviously qualifies under the universal quantifier). Now, by linearity of $L$, this says $L(v)\leq 0$ and $-L(v)\leq 0$ (i.e $L(v)\geq 0$). Hence, $L(v)=0$, so by arbitrariness of $v$, this is the definition of $L=0$.

There's also another proof, which reduces it to the 1-dimensional case using the chain rule.  Fix $v\in\Bbb{R}^n$; we shall show $df_p(v)=0$. To do this, consider the curve $\gamma:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^n$, $\gamma(t)=p+tv$. Now, since $\gamma(0)=p\in U$ and $U$ is open, there is an open interval $I$ around the origin in $\Bbb{R}$ such that $\gamma$ maps $I$ into $U$ (or you can just use continuity of $\gamma$ to say $\gamma^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}$ containing the origin). Now, consider the single-variable function $f\circ\gamma:I\to\Bbb{R}$. We have $(f\circ\gamma)(0)=f(\gamma(0))=f(p)$, so the fact that $f$ is assumed to have a local extremum at $p$ implies that $f\circ\gamma$ has a local extremum at $0$. So, by the [single-variable version of the theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3278356/568204), I'm sure you know that this implies $(f\circ\gamma)'(0)=0$. Now, what is this derivative? The chain rule tells you it is $df_{\gamma(0)}(\gamma'(0))=df_p(v)$. Thus, $df_p(v)=0$, so by arbitrariness of $v$, we have shown $df_p=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. For 2) I got : If $\frac{r(h)}{|h|} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ imply that $\frac{r(tv)}{|tv|} \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ which means that $\frac{r(tv)}{|t|}\frac{1}{v} \to 0$. Since we are assuming that $v$ is nonzero.

Comment: For 2) I'm not sure why my question got cut off. I actually wanted to ask whether we needed v to be a unit vector because I thought the numerator and denominator must have the same norm for the argument to work or at the very least, $v$ should have a small norm, because I thought it was possible that the denominator might go to zero faster than the numerator and r(tv)/t blows up to infinity. But it turns out that's not the case.

Comment: @davidh that's correct, you do not need unit norm for $v$ (though in your first comment you have a typo it shouls be $|v|$ in the denominator).